# Object.assign in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm doing foreach in the messages and get the user information.

```
messages.map(function (message, index) { 
  obj[index] = { 
    id: message._id, 
    createdAt: message.createdAt, 
    text: message.text, 
    img: message.img
  };

  User.findById(message.userId).then((user)=>{ 
  Object.assign(obj[index], {user_id: user._id}, {username: user.username}, {image_photo : user.userId});
}).catch((error)=>{  
 console.log(error); 
});
```

the `Object.assign` it's not working, it's problem from `async` ?

Comment: Can you please fix your post layout and indent the code?

Comment: When u say, it is not working, what do you mean? It is going to the catch block. Or obj[index] is not updated.

Comment: Can you show the error that indicates it's "not working"

Comment: You will probably want to `return` the chained promise from the `map` callback

Comment: Not working means that the values it's not joing to the object.

Comment: `Object.assign` is not async, however, `User.findById(message.userId).then` is.

Comment: @sjahan not working in this case, how i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not maintaining your Promise chain so you're not awaiting any of your Promises. Since you're not waiting for your Promises to finish, the merge against `obj[index]` via your `Object.assign()` hasn't happened by the time your code is beyond this context.

To fix this, you'll need to wait for your entire Promise chain to finish working. Start by returning the Promise from `user.findById()` to `messages.map()`. Since `map()` returns a new array of values which, in this case are Promises, we can take that array and pass it to `Promise.all()`.

[`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all), will wait for all Promises in the given array to finish resolving before invoking a callback registered via `.then()` or can be `return`ed back to another function that has its own Promise chain.

```
// This code assumes let obj = {} is present within scope
let userPromises = messages.map((message, index) => { 
  obj[index] = { 
    id: message._id, 
    createdAt: message.createdAt, 
    text: message.text, 
    img: message.img
  }

  // return the Promise from User.findById()
  return User.findById(message.userId)
    .then(user => ( 
      // Merge obj[index] with user
      Object.assign(obj[index], {user_id: user._id, username: user.username, image_photo : user.userId})
    ))
    .catch(error => console.log(error))
}) 

// return your Promise chain and await all your promises then take an action
return Promise.all(userPromises)
  .then(() => {
    // Will print fully filled with user info
    console.log(JSON.stringify(obj))
  })
```

This can also be written using `async/await`

```
let userPromises = messages.map(async (message, index) => { 
  obj[index] = { 
    id: message._id, 
    createdAt: message.createdAt, 
    text: message.text, 
    img: message.img
  }

  try {    
    // This is equivalent to User.findById(message.userId).then(user => {...})
    let user = await User.findById(message.userId)

    // Merge obj[index] with user
    Object.assign(obj[index], {user_id: user._id, username: user.username, image_photo : user.userId})
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(obj))
  }
})

return Promise.all(userPromises)
  .then(() => console.log(JSON.stringify(obj)))
```

Comment: i need to make push to existing array, how to make that?

Comment: @PauloRodrigues I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Can you be more specific? If you're referring to explicitly returning a value from `message.map()` then you could return the value from `Object.assign()` which will be equivalent to the merged `obj[index]`. This would also be accessible in a result array passed to the `then()` chained to `Promise.all()`.

Comment: I need to put the object in array.push(obj[index])